# How to find the similarity (as a percentage) between two float[] arrays in c#

Tags: c#, floating-point, similarity

I need to get the similarity between two float[] arrays of the same lengths and return have this similarity be returned as a float which will be the percentage. How would you do this in c#?

Comment: Did you try solving this issue by yourself? Can you share the code which you wrote? What problem you are facing there? Can you also share the sample input data and the expected output?

Comment: How do you define "similarity"? What would have a similarity of 1, 0, and 0.5?

Comment: Try `average = (float1 + float2)/2`,  `similarity_as_percentage = 100*(float1 - average)/average`.  Suggest you post what you have tried to add clarity.